# How can I store the values in a varaibles I split from a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to store the values in a variable from the string that I split but I am getting Null everytime I select the variable name. I tried this:

```
DECLARE @MyString varchar(200)
DECLARE @FldName1 varchar(100), @FldName2 varchar(100), @FldName3 varchar(100),
        @FldVal1 varchar(100), @FldVal2 varchar(100), @FldVal3 varchar(100)

SET @MyString = 'Name1 Am Name2 Chin Name3 Fina'

select @FldName1=(parsename(replace(@MyString,' ','.'),6)),
       @FldVal1=(parsename(replace(@MyString,' ','.'),5)),
       @FldName2=(parsename(replace(@MyString,' ','.'),4)),
       @FldVal2=(parsename(replace(@MyString,' ','.'),3)),
       @FldName3=(parsename(replace(@MyString,' ','.'),2)),
       @FldVal3=(parsename(replace(@MyString,' ','.'),1))
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: v17.6. I tried 3 strings and it worked, but for this example, it does not work. I am not sure why.

Comment: @VinaChan v17.6 is probably the version of the SQL Server Management Studio. What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 2):

TSQL [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is only applicable for sql objects `([DBName].[schema].[table])`, that is why its working only for 3 strings.

```
parsename('dbo.tablename',1) will result to 'dbo'
```

You can play around using `string_split()`

```
select * from string_split(@MyString, ' ')
```

Comment: The problem with `STRING_SPLIT` is that it generates an (unordered) _set_ of records as its output.  This means that the OP might not be able to control into which variable each component is stored.

Comment: yes i agree with you @TimBiegeleisen, op might use masking to check which which is the [key] and [value] if using string_split, like 'Name%', but problem is how to join the value related to this [key], unless OP will assign value='Name1-Am'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree. I need to store the values in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may try with one different approach, based on parsing a valid `JSON` text. You need to transform your input data into a valid `JSON` array (`'Name1 Am Name2 Chin Name3 Fina'` is transformed into `'["Name1","Am","Name2","Chin","Name3","Fina"]'`) and then to use `JSON_VALUE()` to get the value for specified item in this array. Note, that `JSON` arrays are zero-based.

Statemnent:

```
DECLARE @MyString varchar(200)
DECLARE @FldName1 varchar(100), @FldName2 varchar(100), @FldName3 varchar(100),
        @FldVal1 varchar(100), @FldVal2 varchar(100), @FldVal3 varchar(100)
SET @MyString = 'Name1 Am Name2 Chin Name3 Fina'

SELECT @MyString = CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@MyString, ' ', '","'), '"]')
SELECT
   @FldName1 = JSON_VALUE(@MyString, '$[5]'),
   @FldVal1  = JSON_VALUE(@MyString, '$[4]'),
   @FldName2 = JSON_VALUE(@MyString, '$[3]'),
   @FldVal2  = JSON_VALUE(@MyString, '$[2]'),
   @FldName3 = JSON_VALUE(@MyString, '$[1]'),
   @FldVal3  = JSON_VALUE(@MyString, '$[0]')
SELECT @FldName1, @FldVal1, @FldName2, @FldVal2, @FldName3, @FldVal3
```